# Vim: Lock top line of a window

Tags: vim

Is it possible in Vim to lock the top line of a window so that the first line in buffer is always seen on top of the window?

I have a file, say, dump of a database table. On the first line there are names of columns, other lines contain data. I want to be able to scroll contents up and down, and always see column names.

N.B. Lines can be lengthy, so I use `nowrap` and want column names and contents to scroll right and left simultaneously. That's why `:1split` doesn't suit -- unless there's a way to scroll two windows at the same time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scroll two windows at the same time, so I think you can do what you want by splitting your window, and locking the scrolling behaviour. See [:scrollbind](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27scrollbind%27) and [this tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Scrolling_synchronously) for more details. Note that you have to lock *each* window in order that they move in sync.

Comment: The is is a good tip, but the scrollbind suggestion needs a little tweaking.  By default scrollbind will sync scrolling in the two windows vertically -- which is exactly what the OP _doesn't_ want, and it won't sync the horizontal scrolling -- which is what the OP does want.  The way to get desired behavior is to adjust the scrolloptions (:set sbo) so that 'ver' is _not_ included and so 'hor' is included.  Then windows will sync horizontally but not vertically.

Comment: @Herbert - thx for the clarification. I'd not explicitly listed the options since I figured :scrollbind was a good starting point, but I think the extra info you've provided is worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Vim has great help system, but sometimes it's difficult to understand what do you actually need.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks guys! Let me summarize the actual commands that did the job for me:

```
:1spl              # create an extra window with only 1 line 
:set scrollbind    # synchronize upper window
ctr+W , arrowDown  # switch to other window
:set scrollbind    # synchronize lower window
:set sbo=hor       # synchronize horizontally
```

Answer (score 3):

Split your window, decrease the top window height, set the top most line to be the first one and get back to the working window.

```
:split
:resize 1
gg
Ctrl-w w
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to scroll down csv files while keeping the headers visible, is there an official way to `:split` and `resize 1` in one command?  It seems that `:99sp` does what I want. But I have `set splitbelow`, and `set splitright` in my `.vimrc` so it may behave differently on your system.